# The program doesn't give output.

Tags: c#, boyer-moore

I have written this Boyer Moore Algorithm in C# code but when  I enter text and pattern it doesn't give any solution.
I was given an algorithm which I had to implement. I did every  bit of logic in code but it wouldn't give solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter String: ");
        string t = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter pattern: ");
        string p = Console.ReadLine();
        string sigma = new String(p.Distinct().ToArray());

        Program pro = new Program();
        pro.BoyerMooreMatcher(t,p,sigma);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public void BoyerMooreMatcher(string t,string p , string sigma) {
     Program pro = new Program();
    int n= t.Length;
    int m = p.Length;
  int[] lambda = pro.badCharacter(p,m,sigma);

    int[] gamma = pro.GoodSuffix(p,m);
    m = m - 1;
    //n = n - 1;
    int s = 0;
        int j=0;

        while(s<=n-m){
            j = m;
            while(j>0 && p[j]==t[s+j]){

                j = j - 1;
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("patter occured at shift ", s);
                    s = s + gamma[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    s = s + Math.Min(gamma[j], j = lambda[t[s + j]]);
                }

                }                                
            }
        }

    public int[] badCharacter(string P, int m, string sigma)
    {
        int[] alpha = new int[256];
        int j;

        foreach(char a in sigma)
        {
            alpha[a] = 0;

        }
        for (j = 0; j <= m-1; j++)
        {
            alpha[P[j]] = j;
        }
        return alpha;
    }

    public int[] GoodSuffix(string P, int m)
    {
      int[] pie = Prefix(P);

     char[] chararray = P.ToCharArray();
     Array.Reverse(chararray);

     string pinv = new string(chararray);
      int[] pieinv = Prefix(pinv);

        int[] gamma= new int[100];
        int j;


         Prefix(pinv.ToString());

        for (j = 0; j <= m; j++)
        {
            gamma[j] = m - pie[m];

        }
        for (int l = 1; l <= m;l++)
        {
            j = m - pieinv[l];
            if (gamma[j] > l - pieinv[l]) {
                gamma[j] = l - pieinv[l];
            }
        }
        return gamma;
    }

    public int[] Prefix(string P)
    {
      int   m = P.Length;
        int k;

        int[] pie= new int[m+1];
       for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
       {
           pie[i] = i;
        }
  //     m = m - 1;

        pie[1] = 0;
        k = 0;

        for (int q = 2; q <= m-1; q++)
        {
            while (k > 0 && P[k + 1] != P[q])
            {
                k = pie[k];
            }
            if (P[k + 1] == P[q])
            {
                k = k + 1;
            }
            pie[q] = k;
        }
        return pie;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for the `Program` class?

Comment: Did you try debugging at all?

Comment: It was just to call the other functions. I

Comment: To call the other functions Tamoghna.
and Alex, yess I did try to but my Array handling is not much good. I'm sorry!

Comment: Run it line by line in the debugger, and see where the values differ than your expectations.  That logic is too complex to be debugged visually.  You could also break the code into smaller functions that can be tested and debugged independently.